# How to query for objects with an ISO date of today?

Tags: typescript, elasticsearch, firebase-realtime-database

I've got this data:

```
[
  ...
  {
      date: {
        startDate: '2017-04-21T00:00:00.000Z',
        endDate: '2017-04-21T00:00:00.000Z',
        startTime: '12:00',
        endTime: '21:00'
      }
    },
    {
      date: {
        startDate: '2017-04-21T00:00:00.000Z',
        endDate: '2017-04-21T00:00:00.000Z',
        startTime: '09:00',
        endTime: '23:00'
      }
    }
  ...
]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
export const OngoingEventsQuery: any = {
  type: 'event',
  body: {
    from: 0,
    size: 2,
    query: {
      range: {
        'date.startDate': {
          gt: new Date().getDate() - 1
        },
        'date.endDate': {
          lt: new Date().getDate() + 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Now what I need to do, is to match objects that match today's date, as well as take `startTime` and `endDate` into account. So if today's date is `april 21 2017` and the time is `15:00`, both of the above objects should match.

Trying without the start- and end time match first, this query gives me every possible object in the database, which is really wrong.

I thought I had to give a date between `yesterday` and `tomorrow` in order to get `today`, by using `getDate()` with either plus one or minus one. But this is obviously wrong.

How can I do this?

**EDIT:** Oddly enough, if I remove `from` and `size` from the query I get 0 results..

Comment: Unless you have no control over the data that goes into ES, I suggest moving all this logic at indexing time and make sure you index the correct date in there (including hour/minutes as well).

Comment: @AndreiStefan I can't do that unfortunately, the data has to be stored like this and indexed like this :/

Comment: Nobody stops you from creating another field (additional to the existent ones) where you have the full timestamp to be used for this kind of range matching. What I'm trying to say is that working around this type of mapping might affect your queries performance.

Comment: And "today" is `now/d`.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I get that, I will most likely look to add another prop in the near future but until then I have to use it like this. Would I put that on both `gt` and `lt`? Because that still gives me 0 results hm.

Comment: Posted as answer regarding `now/d` (the day itself). Regarding the hours, that might require some scripting.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Cuz of timezones?

Comment: That too, but as I see in your sample a time of `09:00` is just a `string` in Elasticsearch and to make a proper comparison at hour level, that needs to be converted in a proper date and compared with today's hour. When I referred to script, I meant a script inside an ES query.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Alright, I will do some digging. Your solution without times works at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date.startDate": {
              "gte": "now/d",
              "lte": "now/d"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date.endDate": {
              "gte": "now/d",
              "lte": "now/d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

From [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/date.html) the dates are kept in UTC internally, so if your comparison will use the UTC time, you should be good to go:

> Internally, dates are converted to UTC (if the time-zone is specified) and stored as a long number representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch.

Comment: Check out my other answer, didn't need a lot of scripting to get it to work :)

Comment: Timezones are not taken into account yet however, not sure how I'll do that one.

Answer (score 0):

Just to build on @AndreiStefan's answer, including the time was as simple as adding two more `range` conditions. So the full query looks like this:

```
export const OngoingEventsQuery: any = {
  type: 'event',
  body: {
    from: 0,
    size: 2,
    query: {
      bool: {
        must: [
          {
            range: {
              'date.startDate': {
                gte: 'now/d',
                lte: 'now/d'
              }
            }
          },
          {
            range: {
              'date.endDate': {
                gte: 'now/d',
                lte: 'now/d'
              }
            }
          },
          {
            range: {
              'date.startTime': {
                lte: datefns.getHours(new Date()) + ':' + datefns.getMinutes(new Date())
              }
            }
          },
          {
            range: {
              'date.endTime': {
                gte: datefns.getHours(new Date()) + ':' + datefns.getMinutes(new Date())
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
};
```

This does not yet take timezones into account however.